# Find all polynomials $P$ for which $(P(x)-x)\mid P^{(n)}(x)-x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

$n\gt1$ is a fixed natural number.  Find all polynomials $P(x)$ with complex coefficients for which $(P(x)-x)\mid P^{(n)}(x)-x,$ where $P^{(n)}()$ is the $n$th iterate: $P^{(1)}(x)=P(x)$ and $P^{(i+1)}(x)$ = $P(P^{(i)}(x))$
.

What I proved until now : I proved $P(x)-x$ does not have any double roots and the problem is equivalent to solving $P(x)-x\mid P^{'}(x)^{n}-1$

Comment: Where does the question come from?

Comment: Previous week RMM TST. Three people solved in exam but still unsolved in all of the forums in aops,...

Comment: I tweaked the notation slightly, since $P^n(x)$ in the polynomial context especially is much too easy to read as a power.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks a lot

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(P(x)-x)^2$ that divides $P^n(x)$? https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1986013p13820149 (If yes, you should ask a new question, because there are already answers here.)

Comment: @punctureddusk Since I had a typo typing this tricky problem, I opened new forum.(Thanks for mentioning)

Comment: Perfect. I'll leave a link here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524657/px-x2-mid-pnx-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $r$ is a root of $P(x)-x$ of order $m$, i.e. $P(x) = x + O((x-r)^m)$ as $x \to r$, then
I claim $P^{(n)}(x) = x + O((x-r)^m)$ as well.  This should be possible to prove by induction on $n$.  Therefore all roots of $P(x) - x$ are roots of $P^{(n)}(x) - x$ with the same or greater multiplicity.  We conclude that $P(x) - x$ always divides $P^{(n)}(x) - x$.

Answer (score 3):

Write
$$P[x,y]=\frac{P(x)-P(y)}{x-y}$$
$$P_1(x)=P[x,P(x)]\text{.}$$

Then
$$P^{\circ n}(x)-x=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}P_1(P^{\circ i}(x))\right)(P(x)-x)$$
witnesses
$$P(x)-x\mid P^{\circ n}(x)-x\text{.}$$

In particular, the ring of scalars is irrelevant.

Comment: This seems interesting. Is it part of a broader theory or a bigger system of ideas?