# Find all polynomials $P$ for which $(P(x)-x)^2\mid P^{(n)}(x)-x$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

$n\gt1$ is a fixed natural number.  Find all polynomials $P(x)$ with complex coefficients for which $(P(x)-x)^2\mid P^{(n)}(x)-x,$ where $P^{(n)}()$ is the $n$th iterate: $P^{(1)}(x)=P(x)$ and $P^{(i+1)}(x)$ = $P(P^{(i)}(x))$
.

What I proved until now : I proved $P(x)-x$ does not have any double roots and the problem is equivalent to solving $P(x)-x\mid P^{'}(x)^{n}-1$.

Comment: I changed the superscript in the last equation to a power, since I think that is what you mean (comparing to what's in the aops topic https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1986013p13820149)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Solution]

Since there is no answer,I post the original answer.

Comment: Can you explain the part with Lagrange interpolation?